# How do I merge call and caller graph in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, call-graph

I have both `CALL_GRAPH` and `CALLER_GRAPH` set to `YES`, and doxygen happily generates both call and caller graph for me, however is there a command or trick to merge these two graphs to a single "flow" graph?

That is, instead of `a->B` and `B->c` how do I get `a->B->c`?

Comment: Are you sure you want that?  If each function in your system calls a small number (say 2) other functions, and the call stack averages 10 layers deep, each function will have 1000 connections to others; your find graph will be unreadable because of all the arcs.  The fact that Doxygen is actually lousy at determining what is actually called (it seems to do pretty poorly with overloads and indirect function calss) will only make this worse.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure :) The project is really small (2 classes and a couple of structs), and I'm heavily refactoring it(C++ so it's manual). The call stack is only 5 deep and most functions only call one other function. If the graphs gets to noisy I'll have to disable them of course, but as it is now, the merge will only consist ~10 items in a straight line.